# SWIFT : Display label

Tags: swift3

I begin to learn swift language and i've a problem.

I try to display a label when i put the button. I show you :

```
    @IBAction func nextRule(sender : UIButton) {
    rule = Rules(game: Int(randomNumber))
}

@IBOutlet var lTitle: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var lRule: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    lTitle.text = rule.title
    lRule.text = rule.rule
```

Rules(game: Int) contain a model whith "title" And "rule"

When i press the button, i want to display a new Rule, is it possible by doing something like his?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about assign your rule to lTitle and lRule like this

```
@IBAction func nextRule(sender : UIButton) {
    rule = Rules(game: Int(randomNumber))
    lTitle.text = rule.title
    lRule.text = rule.rule
}
```